# import langchain => Error : TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, chatbot, langchain

I want to use langchain for my project.

so I installed it using following command : `pip install langchain`

but While importing "langchain" I am facing following Error:

```
File /usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py:774, in _GenericAlias.__subclasscheck__(self, cls)
    772 if self._special:
    773     if not isinstance(cls, _GenericAlias):
--> 774         return issubclass(cls, self.__origin__)
    775     if cls._special:
    776         return issubclass(cls.__origin__, self.__origin__)

TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

Any one who can solve this error ?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and full traceback (not only the last line). But first guess: make sure your own files don't have names colliding with names from the libs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
typing-inspect==0.8.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
```

Comment: We were successful just pinning typing_extensions to 4.5.0. Then again we don't include typing-inspect so YMMV

Comment: This leads to ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
langchain 0.0.162 requires pydantic<2,>=1, which is not installed.
apache-beam 2.49.0 requires protobuf<4.24.0,>=3.20.3, but you have protobuf 3.19.6 which is incompatible.
pydantic-core 2.4.0 requires typing-extensions!=4.7.0,>=4.6.0, but you have typing-extensions 4.5.0 which is incompatible.
torchaudio 0.12.0 requires torch==1.12.0, but you have torch 1.12.1 which is incompatible.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you give the whole command (pip install ...) and more context information

Comment: Too terse to be usable...

Answer (score 25):

So I was trying it for hours and at last I found a solution hope it helps you.

First, I did this:

```
pip install typing-inspect==0.8.0 typing_extensions==4.5.0
```

Then:

```
pip install pydantic -U
```

After this will throw an error but once again I did:

```
pip install pydantic==1.10.11
```

Then it started working.

Comment: Same. It worked after it.

Comment: Where did you insert the following line 'typing-inspect==0.8.0 typing_extensions==4.5.0'. Did you use it as an environment variable?

Comment: You do need `pip install pydantic -U`, directly use `pip install pydantic==1.10.11`.

@Antonio this needs to be run using pip install like `pip install typing-inspect==0.8.0 typing_extensions==4.5.0`

Comment: This solution worked for me.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. But I would like to know the reason behind this.

Answer (score 14):

After installing so many packages got a solution using below package

```
!pip install pydantic -U
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That worked for me as well @Mayur_Ghadge - thank you for your contribution!

Comment: worked here too! had this issue just when importing the csvloader class, and the above typing_extensions did not

Answer (score 5):

Fixed in Pydantic 1.10.8.
For poetry, use `pydantic = "^1.10.8"` in your pyproject.toml file.

Answer (score 2):

Install langchain version 0.0.133. After this version, the error occurs.

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'SUFFIX' from 'langchain.agents.agent_toolkits.pandas.prompt' (/home/konsultera/Downloads/private_chat_gpt/chatgpt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent_toolkits/pandas/prompt.py)   ---> got this Error for the version u have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue got resolved after I changed my Python version - the error was happening on an environment using Python 3.9, I then switched to another environment using Python 3.11 and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score -6):

The error message suggests that there is an issue with the typing module in Python. It seems that the subclass() function is being called with an argument that is not a class.

To solve this error, you can try updating the typing module to the latest version. You can do this by running the following command:

```
pip install
```

If the issue persists, you can also try reinstalling the langchain package:

```
pip uninstall langchain
pip install langchain
```

If none of these solutions work, it is possible that there is a compatibility issue between the langchain package and your Python version. In that case, you may need to use a different version of Python or contact the package maintainers for further assistance.