# Langchain Schema + langchain_openai errors (one resulting after completing the other)

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, langchain, large-language-model

I'm trying to do the following simple code:

```py
from langchain.schema import HumanMessage, SystemMessage
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
```

**1]** If I use it just after installing `langchain` and `langchain_openai` I get the following error:

- ERROR: `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`
- LINE: `from langchain.schema import HumanMessage, SystemMessage`

**2]** I found multiple answers online that are similar to this: [import langchain => Error : TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76314471/20972936) but when I add to my cluster the following installations:

```py
typing-inspect==0.8.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
```

Then I get the following:

- ERROR: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator' from 'typing_extensions' (/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)`
- LINE: `from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI`

---

I'm using Databricks with the following:

- Cluster 1:

  - Runtime: 13.2 ML (includes Apache Spark 3.4.0, GPU, Scala 2.12)
  - Worker & Driver type: Standard_NC21s_v3    224 GB Memory, 2 GPUs
- Cluster 2:

  - Runtime: 12.2 LTS ML (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)
  - Node type: Standard_DS5_v2   56 GB Memory, 16 Cores

Comment: seems some modules are incompatible. would you try to create a virtual environment and then install these `pip install -r requirement.txt` [requirement.txt](https://github.com/simpleappdesigner/debugs/blob/main/requirement.txt), when i tried with these, i received no error(on mac).

Comment: @simpleApp Im using databricks, how can I do it on top of it?