# TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class on Flask / Vercel

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, cloud, vercel

I'm currently trying to host my Flask application on Vercel, but I keep getting the same error,`TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`
Full log:

```
[WARNING]   2024-03-01T18:22:28.551Z        Set both RATELIMIT_LIMIT and RATELIMIT_PERIOD in configuration. Default values are being used.
[ERROR] TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/vc__handler__python.py", line 31, in <module>
    if not issubclass(base, BaseHTTPRequestHandler):INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 2833.05 ms   Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
Unknown application error occurred
```

I tried to change `typing_extension` to 4.5.0, `typing-inspect` to 0.8.0, and`pydantic` to 1.10.11, (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76313592/import-langchain-error-typeerror-issubclass-arg-1-must-be-a-class), but I still kept having the same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not using `issubclass()` correctly.  As the error says, the first arg must be a class.  But you're passing `base` as the first arg, which is not a class.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `isinstance`, not `issubclass`?

Comment: I'm not using issubclass() anywhere in my code.

Comment: Oh, so the error is happening inside some module?  Does the error message identify which module that is?

Comment: It does not, that's the main thing that's stopping me from debugging it myself :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer; I had configured vercel incorrectly.
I used `server.py` as my main method, but vercel requires an `index.py` file. So I created an index.py file, that was a single line; `from server import app`.
then `vercel.json`:
Old:

> {
> "version": 2,
> "builds": [
> {
> "src": "./server.py",
> "use": "@vercel/python"
> }
> ],
> "routes": [
> {
> "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/server.py"
> }
> ]
> }

New:

> {
> "version": 2,
> "builds": [
> {
> "src": "./index.py",
> "use": "@vercel/python"
> }
> ],
> "routes": [
> {
> "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/"
> }
> ]
> }